# Unable to set the event date using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to create an application which syncs the event with S-planner. I used this intent.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
```

I am able to set the title and description using Events.title and Events.description. But when I use

```
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, "2015-04-02");
```

The event doesn't get the date provided by code, rather It takes the current system date and sync it with that value.

Can you please tell me a working way to do that? Will Events.DTSTART work? If so, then How do I provide value for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> public static final String EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME
>
> Added in API level 14
> Intent Extras key: The start time of an event or an instance of a recurring event. (milliseconds since epoch)

You need to pass milliseconds instead of `String` in this extra.